# BrilliantRetail: Is pagination of Customer Orders & Downloads possible?

Tags: brilliantretail

Does anyone know if it is possible to paginate the customer orders and downloads listings on the customer facing orders and downloads pages in BrilliantRetail?

I know you can limit the number of results returned using `limit=“n”`, but can you paginate the results like a standard channel entries tag to allow customers to browse through their entire order and download history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the response I received from a support ticket to BR, this is not possible at the moment (BR 1.6.* release) but is a feature request and should appear sometime in the 1.7.* dev release.